# JBoss Messaging fails over the firewall

Tags: jboss, messaging

I've recently set up JBoss AS 5.1 and implemented a point-to-point messaging service,
where one client produces a message and the other consumes it, which works well
on a localhost, but not the case when the localhost is bound to an ip address and
the client(consumer) is outside the system over the firewall, with the producer within the localhost.
The currently open ports ( by system administrator of my institution ) are :

1098
1099
4444
4457  (  opened to solve -> Problem establishing socket connection for InvokerLocator
[bisocket://???.??.??.???:4457/ )
4460

The ip address is open to public and even the firewall in my Windows 7 is down for test.
The command I use when starting a JBoss AS is

**run.bat -b ???.??.??.??? -c default**

I have not been able to find any clue to the problem since yesterday, completely stuck.
I hope some guru may wake me up.

Error message goes like

**org.jboss.jms.exception.MessagingNetworkFailureException**

at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.DelegateSupport.handleThrowable(DelegateSupport.java:245)

at ... blah blah...

Comment: I've found a solution to this.
What I did was uncomment 



<attribute name="secondaryBindPort">4460</attribute>     



in remoting-bisocket-service.xml



and give it an available port.



And the connection was successful.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was uncomment

```
<attribute name="secondaryBindPort"> 4460 </attribute>
```

in remoting-bisocket-service.xml and give it an available port. After restarting JBoss AS(5.1), it started to work.